# (Databricks Ad monetisation example) How do I find the latest match in a stream?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

In the blog post ["Introducing Stream-Stream Joins in Apache Spark 2.3"](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/03/13/introducing-stream-stream-joins-in-apache-spark-2-3.html) joining clicks with impressions based on their adId is discussed:

```python
# Define watermarks
impressionsWithWatermark = impressions \
  .selectExpr("adId AS impressionAdId", "impressionTime") \
  .withWatermark("impressionTime", "10 seconds ")   # max 10 seconds late

clicksWithWatermark = clicks \
  .selectExpr("adId AS clickAdId", "clickTime") \
  .withWatermark("clickTime", "20 seconds")        # max 20 seconds late

# Inner join with time range conditions
impressionsWithWatermark.join(
  clicksWithWatermark,
  expr(""" 
   clickAdId = impressionAdId AND 
    clickTime >= impressionTime AND 
    clickTime <= impressionTime + interval 1 minutes    
    """
  )
)
```

I'd like to know if its possible to filter the resulting stream so that only the rows with latest clickTime are included in each "query interval".

The query interval is the interval given in the query join condition:

```
clickTime >= impressionTime AND 
clickTime <= impressionTime + interval 1 minutes
```

So I might get the following sequence

```
{type:impression, impressionAdId:1, timestamp: 1}
{type:click, clickAdId:1, timestamp: 1}
{type:click, clickAdId:1, timestamp: 15}
```

And after t=60s or so spark emits the following row in the dataframe:

```
{impressionTimestamp: 1, clickTimestamp: 15: clickAddId: 1, impressionAdId: 1}
```

I only posted python code because that was what was in the article, answers with java or scala code are welcome too.